# in case and if in American English

Tags: conditional-constructions, conjunctions

Is the following use of "in case" natural in American English?

> In case you can't find my house, just call me.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: The difference is that we usually use ***in case*** to reference a possible adverse future situation *which will be mitigated or avoided* by something being done / offered / suggested ***now***. For example, ***In case** it's dark you should take a torch* refers to the possibility of it being dark later on (at which time a torch would be useful). But ***If** it's dark you should take a torch* is a fairly unlikely utterance which would *probably* imply the speaker doesn't know if it's *(**currently**)* dark - but if so, you need the torch.

Comment: ...in short, for your *specific* example, I would only expect ***if***. The alternative would work in, say, ***In case** you can't find my house, here's my spare mobile phone [so you can call me].* That works because speaker is offering a "solution" *at time of speaking* (lending addressee a spare phone), rather than simply suggesting potential remedial action in the future (***if*** the adverse situation *does in fact* arise).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Since prepositional *because* has become commonplace in recent years, maybe prepositional *if* will follow. It would make for more succinct warning signs: *If fire break glass*, *If emergency dial 0*.

Comment: @choster: I'm quite sure you're right! I don't specifically recall seeing one yet, but it wouldn't surprise me in the least if ***If fire break glass*** weren't already in use. It seems "unexceptional" to me in the context of, say, a hotel in a *non-native* Anglophone country where many people (especially those in the hospitality / tourism industry) have a fair working knowledge of English. So they'd be biased towards such "simplified" signage because they'd expect more people to understand it quicker, which matters far more than what pernickety / outdated language mavens might think.

Comment: I got used to it when I was learning programming, `if (myVar)` as opposed as a shorthand for `if (myVar <> null)` and all that, but it took some getting used to. But if everyone in the world is taking coding classes, maybe it'll flip back around and we'll have cases again, except that you need to wrap them. `switch (event) case 'water landing', your seat cushion can be used as a flotation device…

Comment: It is just a hair's breadth away from being natural.  ***In case you have any trouble finding my house**, give me a call.*.  We need something more nuanced than a binary condition, which calls for **if**.  ***If you can't find my house**, give me a call.*  **if** could be used in either sentence, but **in case** really wants something of a scenario.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Did you mean to say " it wouldn't surprise me in the least if If fire break glass weren't already in use" or "it wouldn't surprise me in the least if If fire break glass WERE already in use"?

Comment: @Apollyon: Very good point! I recall that as I wrote those words, I paused to think about it. My *natural* inclination was to negate the ***if-*** clause, but looking back at it I started to have my doubts, since the semantics don't exactly work out. In the end I decided to stick with my initial preference, (which [*does actually occur in writing occasionally*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22surprise+me+if+he+weren%27t%22)). If the comment space were bigger I might have added something like *It wouldn't surprise me if someone weren't to query this usage,* but I ran out of space! :)